# Ошибка "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Tags: mysql

> Warning: `mysql_fetch_array()`: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/h30170/data/www/site.ru/indextest.php on line 10
> Наше меню:
>
> Warning: `mysql_fetch_array()`: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/h30170/data/www/site.ru/indextest.php on line 23
> []
>
> Warning: `mysql_fetch_array()`: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/h30170/data/www/site.ru/indextest.php on line 25

На данном сервере никак не могу подключиться к базе, создал простой файл с подключением к БД и вот он результат. Ошибки line 10, 23 и 25.

Comment: То, что вы скармливаете mysql_fetch_array не есть результат mysql_query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы избежать подобных ошибок, используйте проверки:

1. Следуя [этому](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), проверяйте не является ли результат функции `$link == FALSE`
2. Следуя [этому](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php), проверяйте, если результат `TRUE` значит выбрана БД
3. Следуя [этому](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), делайте проверку на `FALSE`, иначе для запросов `SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN` вы получите [`resource`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), а для запросов `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP` - `TRUE`
4. Более того, для детального описания проблемы, используйте [`mysql_error`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php), использовать ее, правда, придется обдуманно, так как ошибку она возвращает для последнего запроса